# An error "Call to constructor of ' ' is ambiguous", although the class's constructor parameters do not look the same?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

There is an error message that appears `Call to constructor of 'Binary' is ambiguous`, that error message just appears when using `LLVM` compiler on macOS but on windows, it doesn't appear.
Also, the class's constructor parameters do not look the same.

```
class Binary {
public:
    Binary() = default;
    Binary(uintmax_t containerSize);
    Binary(unsigned char binary);
    Binary(std::initializer_list<unsigned char> binaryList);
    // .....
};

// When using
// fileSize is `std::streamoff` data type
Binary fileContent((unsigned long long)fileSize)  // << This line is causing the problem.
```

**What's wrong with my class?**

Comment: If the intent is to invoke the second ctor, why cast to `unsigned long long` and not `uintmax_t` ? I'm betting those are the same type roots on your Windows build, but different on your MacOS build.

Comment: `uintmax_t` is `unsigned long long`, so I thought `unsigned long long` was appropriate, also, I did the same thing on macOS and windows but windows doesn't appear that message.

Comment: Yeah, we got that; you said as much in your post. Now read what I said again, specifically how `uintmax_t` on different platforms is **not** necessarily going to be synonymous with `unsigned long long`, so your first statement, `uintmax_t` is `unsigned long long` is *not* universally accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`uintmax_t` is a typedef for the maximum-width unsigned integer type on your machine. When compiling your code, if that type is not *exactly* `unsigned long long`, then this call:

```
Binary fileContent((unsigned long long)fileSize);
```

is ambiguous, since the argument will need to undergo exactly one conversion to match either one of these constructors:

```
Binary(uintmax_t containerSize); // conversion from unsigned long long to uintmax_t needed
Binary(unsigned char binary);    // conversion from unsigned long long to unsigned char needed
```

and the compiler can't choose between them, and there's an error.

If `uintmax_t` happens to be *exactly* `unsigned long long`, then the 1st constructor is an exact match, and is chosen, and the program compiles. Presumably, this is the difference between the macOS, and Windows compiler version that you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the similarity between `uintmax_t` and `unsigned char` that make the compiler think the two are the same?

Comment: No, there's no similarity between `uintmax_t` and `unsigned char`. In fact, they are both equally different from `unsigned long long`, and that's why the compiler can't choose. Edited the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I found `uintmax_t` declared in this way `typedef long unsigned int uintmax_t` and `typedef long long unsigned int uintmax_t`.

Comment: Yes, the first requires a conversion, and the second is an exact match.